# How to target a div by class name inside another class

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent-child, children, css-selectors

I have some divs like this.

```
<div class"parent">
    <div class"child">
     Some Stuff Here
    </div>
</div>


<div class"parent">
    <div class"child">
     Some other kinda Stuff Here
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to click parent class and show the child class only inside that parent without showing the other children classes in other parent classes.

```
$(document).on('click', '.parent', function(){
    $(this).find($('.child').show(500));
});
```

Comment: `<div class="parent">` and `<div class="child">`... you have invalid markup, and mismatching parentheses: `$(this).find(<selector>).show(500);` <-- you're currently selecting _all_ `.child` elements, not just the children

Comment: Use `$(this).find('.child').show(500);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass a selector string to `find()` not an object - you are passing a jQuery object. You also have invalid HTML because `class"parent"` should be `class="parent"`.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4w9uG/)**

```
$(document).on('click', '.parent', function(){
    $(this).find('.child').show(500);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all you need to correct your markup as there should be `=` between attribute `class` and its value. So markup should be like :

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child" >
     Some Stuff Here
    </div>
</div>
```

Try this :

```
$(document).on('click', '.parent', function(){
    $(this).children('.child').show(500);
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d2Tsg/4/)**

Answer (score 1):

Do no use selector `$('.child')` in find, as it will return all the child in DOM and find , `$(this).find($('.child').show(500));` should be `$(this).find('.child').show(500);`

Also correct the html, `class"parent"` should be `class="parent"`, same applies to `class"child"`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/4w9uG/1/)**

```
$(document).on('click', '.parent', function(){
    $(this).find('.child').show(500);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to correct the HTML as

```
<div class="child">
```

'=' is missing in your markup

The following line is enough:

```
$(document).on('click', '.parent', function(){
   $(this).find('.child').show(500);
});
```